# Remove file using MulterGoogleStorage and NestJS

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, nestjs, multer

How to remove file from Google storage bucket using MulterGoogleStorage and NestJS? I can't find any example or docs.
I have next storage for upload files:

```
const storage = new MulterGoogleStorage({
  projectId: 'myprojectId',
  keyFilename: path.join(__dirname, '../../../mykeyfile.json'),
  bucket: 'mybucketname',
  filename: (req: Request, file, cb) => {
    let dir = '';
    const filePath = file.originalname.split('/');        
    if(filePath.length > 1) {
        dir = `${filePath[0]}/`;
    }
    const fileExt = file.originalname.split('.').pop();
    cb(null, `${dir}${Date.now()}.${fileExt}`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create something like this, which would iterate over an array containing all the objects, and would delete.

This uses the [delete](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-objects#storage-delete-object-nodejs) function on the Google Cloud Storage documentation.

```
const storage = new Storage({keyFilename: 'google-credentials.json'});
const imagesToDelete = ['fileName1', 'fileName2', 'fileName3'];
    
    imagesToDelete.map(async (image) => {
      await storage
        .bucket('yourbucketName')
        .file(image)
        .delete();
    });
```

Comment: Thx a lot, it work! I want to use MulterGoogleStorage but seems your offer is single way to resolve this issue. I'll wait a week, may be anybody find other solution, I'll accept your answer.